# How to retrieve `custom_field` values from the Stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a [Payment Link](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links) in Stripe where customers can buy a Product.

The Payment Link page has a [Custom Field](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-fields) that customers have to fill in.

Using the Stripe API, I want to retrieve all values for that custom field.

I have tried the `/v1/payments` and `/v1/payment_intents` endpoints, but even when I `expand[]` all available objects, none have `custom_fields`.

How do I do this? Which URL endpoint do I use? Which object(s) contains this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to retrieve the Checkout Sessions : https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list

Comment: Awesome! For my specific use-case, I had to check that `status` == `complete` to only list values from actual payments.